# Windows service custom commands from command line

Tags: c#, windows, service, command

I've implemented a Windows Service with custom commands overriding OnCustomCommand method.

I can access these custom commands from another .net application with:

```
ServiceController Controller = new ServiceController("MyWindowsService");
if (Controller.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
  {
      Controller.ExecuteCommand(128);
  }
```

But, can I access these custom commands from the command line (cmd) the same way I can start/stop/... the service?

EDIT: (Without creating a middleware application to handle the service, just with standard tools)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Service Control command line tool `sc`

```
> sc control MyWindowsService 128
```

(Under the hood everything is using Win32's `ControlService` API.)