# How to call .NET's ServiceBase.OnCustomCommand method from Python?

Tags: c#, python, .net, wcf, windows-services

I have a Windows service (using C# in .NET `4.7.2`, per [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer)), that implements `ServiceBase.OnCustomCommand` ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.oncustomcommand?view=netframework-4.8)).

I have a Python `3.6` script that needs call the `OnCustomCommand` method.  How can one call `OnCustomCommand` from Python?

---

**Where I Looked**

I see Python has [pywinservicemanager](https://github.com/belvedere-trading/pywinservicemanager#serviceentity), but it seems to not have implemented `OnCustomCommand`.  I may be wrong.

**Best Solution I Came Up With**

I see from [Windows service custom commands from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33888866/11163122) that I can use `sc control`.  My current best solution is to use something like this:

```
import os
os.system('sc control MyService 42`)
```

---

Thank you in advance for your help!